# Regex (leading zeros)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to allow only strings in form of: `.0.2` or `.1.2.3` or `.0.8.9.87`.

But with NO leading zeros. Here is what I got so far `^(\.[0-9])*$`

This should fail: `.0.02`

Comment: Your last example has a leading 0.

Comment: Seems like you need to escape the `.` character. It is a reserved character, and used as a wildcard.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which strings should pass and which should fail? What flavour of regex (PHP, perl etc)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @XaviLópez I have escape character, it is not displayed here properly

Comment: @Alex just because the documents (MIB files) used by the system never have the pattern where zero is repeated twice in OID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, if I got your requirement right:

```
^(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*))+$
```

It will be a dot `.` followed by number without leading 0, and arbitrary number of such instance may follow.

Comment: Yes, you have got my requirement right. Thank you very much for helping out. I'm not good in regular expressions =)